# Group by with diff percentage MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have been trying to query the increase percentage of a product grouped in certain range depending on the actual increase for each run.  So for example I have the following table schema

[image: product table]

Now, if I query the increase percent I would get something like:

```
SELECT *, (((newPrice - price)/price) * 100 ) as PERCENTAGE FROM Product
```

[image: products with their respective percentage]

What Im trying to obtain is to group the values within a particular range depending on the calculated increase. So for this run something like this:

```
| Range   | #COUNT    |
| 0-10%   | 3         | 
| 30-40%  | 1         |
```

*and more ranges and products if existing*

I have tried:

```
Select *, COUNT(idProduct) AS COUNT FROM Product 
where (((newPrice - price)/price) * 100 ) BETWEEN 0 AND 10
```

which gives me:

[image]

But I need to configure the query in a way it can determine a reasonable percent range (i.e Without hard coding the values BETWEEN **0** AND **10**) and group the values in there for different runs. Any ideas?

Thank you!

---

product table

```
CREATE  TABLE `product` (    
  `idproduct` INT NOT NULL ,    
  `description` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,    
  `price` INT NULL ,    
  `newPrice` INT NULL ,    
  PRIMARY KEY (`idproduct`) );
```

Comment: Setup query for anyone who wants to try it out: http://www.sqlize.com/y6pqT7Ys7y

Comment: yes that is a good idea one moment..

Comment: At least where I live, a price increase is defined as `PriceChange / OldPrice` instead of `PriceChange / NewPrice`

Comment: Yes, this is simple test table.. I need to implement that in a more complex table but is basically the same functionality.. thnks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could `group by` 10% percentage bands:

```
SELECT  floor((newPrice - price) / price * 10) * 10 as LowerBound
,       floor((newPrice - price) / price * 10) * 10 + 10 as HigherBound
,       count(*) as Count
FROM    Product
GROUP BY
        floor((newPrice - price) / price * 10)
```

Multiplying by 10 and rounding down should create one group per 10 percentage points.

Comment: Awesome answer +1 and marked as answered!!! I just edited the formula to calculate the increase price. it was my bad I wrote it incorrectly on the question it should be (newPrice - price) / price ..) But awesome!! MANY THANKS!!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  r.RangeValue,
  COUNT(*) AS CountofProducts
FROM (SELECT 
        CASE WHEN (((newPrice - price)/newPrice) * 100 ) <= 10 THEN
          '0-10%'
        WHEN (((newPrice - price)/newPrice) * 100 ) <= 20 THEN
          '10-20%'
        WHEN (((newPrice - price)/newPrice) * 100 ) <= 30 THEN
          '20-30%'
        WHEN (((newPrice - price)/newPrice) * 100 ) <= 40 THEN
          '30-40%'
        ELSE
          '40+%'
        END AS RangeValue
      FROM Product) r
GROUP BY r.RangeValue
```

Comment: I would like to avoid hard coding the ranges. Because I wont have control over them.. I am thinking to manage that within the query depending on the calculated percent ranges

Comment: You have an extra `(` in each CASE statement, and you need to backtick the `Range` field since it is a MySql keyword: http://www.sqlize.com/hXhD843eU2

Answer (score 0):

Its simple 
SELECT count(*) as items, (((newPrice - price)/newPrice) * 100 ) as PERCENTAGE ,

IF ( 
     ((newPrice - price)/newPrice* 100) >=0 &&
     ((newPrice - price)/newPrice* 100) <=10 , 
     "0 - 10%" ,
     IF ( 
         ((newPrice - price)/newPrice* 100) >=11 &&
         ((newPrice - price)/newPrice* 100) <=30 , 
         "10 - 30%",
         *so on....*
     ) 
  )  **AS** 'range'

FROM Product
group by range

Basically, you have to use nested if() statements and inside them you put the ranges.

Then give it a meaningful alias. You can then group by the alias.

Comment: This is a faster way than subquery. you can check by explain mode